# Как сформировать URL через GET форму

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, get

Есть форма

```
<form  method="GET">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Москва"><label>Москва</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Лондон" value="Java"><label>Лондон</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Париж" value="PHP"><label>Париж</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Вашингтон" value="HTML/CSS"> 
    <label>Вашингтон</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Подобрать"/>
</form>
```

Как сделать чтобы при выборе, например, Москвы осуществлялся переход по URL:

> **`sait.ru/search/москва`**

Если выбрать два города, то переход:

> `sait.ru/search/москва+лондон`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Вешаем обработчик на событие [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) у формы
- Как-нибудь получаем все флажки формы (то есть элементы [`<input type="checkbox">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox))
- [Фильтруем](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) выбранные флажки (по `element.checked`)
- Получаем [атрибут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) `name` у флажков
- Конкатенируем через [`array.join('+')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- Переходим на страницу поиска, изменяя [`window.locatin.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
  const checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  const query = [...checkboxes]
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.name)
    .join('+')
  const url = 'https://example.ru/search/' + query;

  // not working in sandbox
  // window.location.href = url;
  alert('redirect to ' + url);
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Москва"><label>Москва</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Лондон" value="Java"><label>Лондон</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Париж" value="PHP"><label>Париж</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Вашингтон" value="HTML/CSS"><label>Вашингтон</label>
  <button>Подобрать</button>
</form>
```

Comment: alert работает а вот window.location.href нет при клике по кнопке в url появляется index.html?Вашингтон=Вашингтон